# what is basic difference between [ #include <qicon.h> ] and [#include <QIcon>] in qt c++?

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt C++ we can include different file but with same functionality like **qicon.h** and **QIcon**. I have following questation on this.

1. what is basic difference between this two different include file?
2. What is advantages or disadvantage of using one either other.
3. If any one have link of qt documentation on this please share the link.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qicon.html) you should use the officially supported header: `#include <QIcon>`.

Comment: You could find the answer after looking into the `QIcon` file.

Comment: Both will work however my advice is to just do what the documentation recommends and use `#include <QIcon>` even though it's unlikely that the Qt developers would change their naming scheme in the future to break including `qicon.h`. And yes if you look a the QIcon file it will solve any mystery on what is going on.

Comment: QIcon ist the class, qicon.h is the written file